# How to return Integer in Laravel (not JSON)

Tags: php, laravel

I have this text `{price:100}`. How can I remove string and the output will be //100

```
function each() {
    $Offer_price = Offer::select('price')->get();
    foreach ($Offer_price as $Price) {
        return  $Price; // I Want The Output 100 Not {price:100}
    }
}
```

Comment: fyi, a `return` statement inside a `foreach` is kind of useless, you'll get the first element from the loop only

Answer (score 3):

If you are sure `$Price` is of `string` type, try:

```
return json_decode($Price, true)['price'];
```

But if objects are automatically converted to JSON (by your framework), try:

```
return $Price->price;
```

Comment: Thank You Very Much It's Worked For Me Thank You My Friend I Search For This Problem A Lot Of Time But I didn't Find Any Thing

Comment: @FullStackDeveloper If this was helpful, consider accepting as answer and/or upvoting (there should be a tick-mark and up-arrow button somewhere above).

Comment: @FullStackDeveloper That worked for you? `{price:100}` doesn't look like valid JSON, `print_r(json_decode('{price:100}'));` doesn't do anything for me

Comment: @brombeer Maybe it was leaved out while posting question, I mean yes, it would only be valid with quotes, like: `{"price" : 100}`

Answer (score 1):

First I would use `json_decode` to get your string into a json object. And then I would access `price` attribute like that:

```
  return json_decode($Price)->{'price'};
```